# Using Appendo and Wordpress Media Uploader

Tags: jquery, ajax

Has anyone had trouble ever trying to implement this?

I can't figure out why mine doesn't work. I can only get the first list element to work properly. If I try to add another upload button with Appendo it is not clickable. Any reason why this is?

This is just a guess, but does jQuery know how many instances of a class there are when the page is loaded? If so, do I need to handle this with AJAX then?

I understand this is a very vague question, but for sake of posting a bunch of code I thought I would see if someone had a similar problem with Appendo. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I ditched appendo and used the jQuery's clone method instead which results in the following code

```
$("#cloner").bind('click', function(){
    $('#div').clone(true).appendTo('#container');
});
```

However, if you want to use appendo and have a button, you need to set copyHandlers to true. This tells it to copy EVERYTHING including event handlers so the button will work.

```
$('#div').appendo({
    copyHandlers: true,
});
```